# Event Listeners inside function store in Variable

Tags: javascript, function

Well, the idea of my problem is a little bit dumb and I know it but please try to understand.
I'm in a position that I need to implement something like this:

```js
var func1 = function(){
    $("#btn1").on("click", function(){
        console.log("From fucntion 1 button 1");
    })
    $("#btn2").on("click", function(){
        console.log("From fucntion 1 button 2");
    })
}
var func2 = function(){
    $("#btn1").on("click", function(){
        console.log("From fucntion 2 button 1");
    })
    $("#btn2").on("click", function(){
        console.log("From fucntion 2 button 2");
    })
}

var fn;
function changefn1(){
    console.log("function change to 1");
    fn = func1;
    fn();
}
function changefn2(){
    console.log("function change to 2");
    fn = func2;
    fn();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="changefn1()">Change function to 1</button>
<button onClick="changefn2()">Change function to 2</button>
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>
```

So yeah the event listeners are working properly but when I click the two Change function button the two event listeners are triggered together. I know that I can just put some condition inside the listeners, let just say that inserting condition will take a while to be implemented.
Then, is there another way to do this correctly and properly.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the event listeners multiple times. Every time you run one of your functions it will re-add the event listeners, causing the callbacks to trigger multiple times. You can remove the click event listeners before adding them using jQuery's `.off()` method:

```js
var func1 = function() {
  $('button').off('click');
  $("#btn1").on("click", function() {
    console.log("From fucntion 1 button 1");
  })
  $("#btn2").on("click", function() {
    console.log("From fucntion 1 button 2");
  })
}
var func2 = function() {
  $('button').off('click'); // remove any click event listeners on your buttons
  $("#btn1").on("click", function() {
    console.log("From fucntion 2 button 1");
  })
  $("#btn2").on("click", function() {
    console.log("From fucntion 2 button 2");
  })
}

var fn;

function changefn1() {
  console.log("function change to 1");
  fn = func1;
  fn();
}

function changefn2() {
  console.log("function change to 2");
  fn = func2;
  fn();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="changefn1()">Change function to 1</button>
<button onClick="changefn2()">Change function to 2</button>
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>
```

An easier way would be to just use one event listener for your clicks, and instead use an object which stores callback functions which would decide which code should execute based on the button selected:

```js
var function_sel = "fn1"; // default function to use
var button_opt = {
  "fn1": function(n) {
    console.log("From function 1 button " +n);
  },
  "fn2": function(n) {
    console.log("From function 2 button " +n);
  }
}

$(".change-btn").click(function() {
  var function_num = $(this).data("fn");
  console.log("function change to " +function_num);
  function_sel = "fn" + function_num;
});

$(".btn").click(function() {
  var button_num = $(this).data("btn");
  button_opt[function_sel](button_num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="change-btn" data-fn="1">Change function to 1</button>
<button class="change-btn" data-fn="2">Change function to 2</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn1" data-btn="1">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn2" data-btn="2">Button 2</button>
```

Comment: yup, I tried something like that. And it is one of my options if there are no other easier way.

Comment: @Francisaskquestion I've added another way you might approach the same problem. It's more extendable and easier to manage

Comment: That is much easier to manage. Thanks, will put this on my options